# How to typeset talltblr's remark and notes like the last spanned row

Tags: tabularray, tablenotes

I need to typeset table notes and sometime even reference them in a table body.
So i tried to use `talltblr` environment for floating tables.

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}                  % a5 paper
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                     % input encoding
\usepackage[english]{babel}                     % localization
\usepackage{caption}                            % caption control
\usepackage{indentfirst}                        % first line indent
\usepackage{tabularray}                         % tabularray package
\usepackage[unicode=true,                       % unicode encoded pdf strings
            colorlinks=true,                    % use colored links
            linkcolor=black,                    % color of links
           ]{hyperref}

\captionsetup[table]
             {labelsep=period,                  % caption separation for tables
              position=t,                       % caption position for tables
              justification=raggedright,        % caption alignment for tables
              singlelinecheck=off,              % don't center single line table captions
              aboveskip=0.5em}                  % above skip for table captions


\newcommand{\normalparindent}{5ex}
\parindent=\normalparindent


\ExplSyntaxOn
% Period separator
\DefTblrTemplate { caption-sep } { mycapsep } { .\enskip }

% My own caption template
\DefTblrTemplate { caption } { mycaption }
  {
    \UseTblrAlign { caption }
    \UseTblrIndent { caption }
    \UseTblrHang { caption }
    \leavevmode
    \makebox [ \linewidth ] [ l ]
      {
        \parbox { \textwidth }
          {
            \raggedright
            \strut
            \UseTblrTemplate { caption-tag } { default }
            \UseTblrTemplate { caption-sep } { mycapsep }
            \UseTblrTemplate { caption-text } { default }
            \strut
          }
      }
  }

% Tabularray theme using mycaption template
\NewTblrTheme { mycaptiontheme }
  {
    \SetTblrTemplate { caption } { mycaption }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{table}[!h]
 \begin{talltblr}
       [theme = mycaptiontheme,
        caption = {Simple floating three part table with two or more notes},
        label = {tab:table-simple-mycaption-notes},
        note{1} = {The first note text. And a long line of dummy text.},
        note{2} = {The first note text. And a long line of dummy text.}]
       {colspec = {ccc},
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
        hline{1,2,Z} = {1pt},
        vlines = {1pt},
        hspan = minimal}
  Head:A    & Head:B    & Head:C    \\
  A1        & B1        & C1        \\
  A2        & B2        & C2        \\
  A3        & B3        & C3        \\
 \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!h]
 \begin{talltblr}
       [theme = mycaptiontheme,
        caption = {Simple floating three part table with two or more notes},
        label = {tab:table-simple-mycaption-note},
        remark{Note} = {The single note text.
                        And a long line of dummy text.
                        And another long line of dummy text.}]
       {colspec = {ccc},
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
        hline{1,2,Z} = {1pt},
        vlines = {1pt},
        hspan = minimal}
  Head:A    & Head:B    & Head:C    \\
  A1        & B1        & C1        \\
  A2        & B2        & C2        \\
  A3        & B3        & C3        \\
 \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And the layout:
[image: Two tables with notes]

But i want the notes and remark to use paragraph indentation and to look like they typeset in the last spanned table row (i.s. horizontal and vertical lines and spacing should be used). Just like it shown on the next picture:

[image: Desirable layout for two tables]

Is there a way to do such a thing?